# How can I use a html Anchor to link to page and then execute the javascript function on that page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've written a script that changes the content of a div in the main part of the html,
using:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "the stuff I want to put in the main box";
```

and an array storing the content so I call changetxt(1) it will change the innerhtml to 'content[1]'etc.)

What I now want to do is link from another page including the changed content, so for example I link to the 'where we meet' content section, (content[2]) but when I link to the html it obviously just shows the default value, I was wondering if there is some way I can link to the content via an Anchor on another page such as -

```
href="index.html-javascript:changetxt(2);
```

I've not found anything on google or this site explaining how to do so.

many thanks

Comment: You can't. One possible way is to make security hole in your page and allow XSS, but I don't think you need that ;)

Comment: @antyrat I am interested how one could make a security hole in their page to allow this..

Comment: You need to parse GET data from url

Comment: That's not the same thing. Besides it will take you to a page in the same site so it's not XSS.

Comment: build an api for your site. Then the other site uses the api tokens and can change the content maybe using GET/POST data to that url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use hash tags?

The link:

`index.html#2`

The javascript in the new page (index.html):

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  var num = Number(window.location.hash.substr(1));

  if(num > 0) {
    changetxt(num);
  }
}
```